# How can I wrap button text in Opera?

Tags: button, opera, word-wrap

I have almost created a website that works in all major browsers flawlessly. Yesterday, I celebrated because that was true. Today, I found out that it is not.

Apparently, Opera won't wrap text on buttons. I tried everything that popped up in my searches - from spacing to outdated Mozilla Firefox hacks.

How can I tell Opera to wrap text on a button? Shortening the text is not an option, as the shortest it could be is still too long.

## EDIT:

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JavaAndCSharp/grX4H/

Comment: could you provide example code? Are we talking inputs of type button or button element or both or something else?

Comment: It would help if you'd actually list the things you have tried and by using which HTML code. Which version of Opera, which operating system etc. You know, the basic troubleshooting background information.

Comment: @eis: Windows 7/XP/8 Dev Preview; see the JSFiddle for the HTML/CSS; opera 11.61 - latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm, yes it does? I didn't even do anything other than define the width of the button. I'd suggest that you have conflicting CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qgdzx/

HTML:

```
<button>This is really long button text that should wrap after I define a fixed-width.</button>
```

CSS:

```
button{
    width:60px;
}
```

Output:

[image]

---

Edit after your update http://jsfiddle.net/CJbae/

HTML:

```
<form>
    <button id="littleWorld" type="button">really really long text that will probably overflow on opera</button> 
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#littleWorld{
    border-radius:40px;
    border-width:0px;
    width:250px;
    height:250px; 
    background-color:#808080;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF; 
}
```

[image: rounded button]

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect your jsfiddle.

Comment: Hooray! It works now! Thank you *so* much. I was about to give up, especially after hallvors's answer.

Comment: Until hallvor answered, I wasn't aware that `<input type="button" />` and `<button/>` rendered differently. I've been using button for so long I forgot about the input type. heh.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a known issue in Opera, where more text formatting will be applied to BUTTON elements than to INPUT type=button. They should be equivalent, really.

I hope using BUTTON instead of INPUT type="button" is an acceptable workaround for you (fingers crossed - BUTTON might cause other rendering problems in other browsers..)

Seems Opera already has a bug on this - internally it's CORE-45335.