# Layout of pseudoelements inside a button in Opera

Tags: css, button, opera

I'm trying to [use the `:before` and `:after` pseudoelements to add an icon](http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-gui-icons/) to `<button/>` element.  While it  works fine for Chrome/Firefox/IE it breaks on Opera because its layout mechanism seems to be different.  After some testing, I reduced it down to the following test case:

```
<style>
  .foo {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: cyan;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .foo:after {
    background: lime;
    border: 10px solid yellow;
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
    top: 25px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }
</style>
<div    class="foo">&nbsp;</div>
<button class="foo">&nbsp;</button>
```

Here, two different elements are styled with the same class.  One would expect them to show approximately the same layout (and indeed it is the case in non-Opera browsers), but on Opera the layouts are drastically different:

[image: comparison between Chrome and Opera]

This was tested using Chrome 33.0 and Opera 12.16 on Windows 7.  It doesn't affect other subelements though, only the pseudoelements.

Is there a way to mitigate this problem without using "real" subelements?

(I should note that even after making the two elements have completely identical computed styles in Dragonfly, the problem still occurs.)

Comment: did you check http://caniuse.com/#search=button? looks like that 12% to 100% makes the difference..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I wrap button text in Opera?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871121/how-can-i-wrap-button-text-in-opera)